# Parent form is not invalid when a two level nested cva is invalid

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I work on an angular 7 project and use nested forms implementing the interface [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor)

In case of a form which uses a CVA everything works fine but when I use an CVA which itselfs uses an CVA I face a problem with validation. When I set a value of the last nested CVA in the parent form to an invalid value the parent form is not invalid. But in case of one nested CVA it works.

In both cases when I start to write something in the input field and my input is invalid then it works in both cases. The parent is always invalid just when I use the setValue method it does not always work.

To be more clear I provided a very simple example on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hgxo9p

Here is also a screenshot of the example:

[image]

The first one is only one nested CVA. 2 is invalid because there must be a minimum length of 2. Below, you can see, that the CVA and the form in the app component is not valid as expected.

In the second example the input is also invalid. Here in both CVAs we can see that the form is invalid but not in the app form itself.

But, when I start to change the input in both examples then it works. See the screenshot below:

[image]

I analysed it for a while but I can't find out what the problem is or what I'm missing. Does anyone know what's causing the issue?

Comment: Why don't you transmit form ref with @Input() to the child?

Comment: you has in write `this.group.setValue(value, {emitEvent: false});`, So not realize the validation. remove the `{emitEvent:false}` to work

Comment: @Yin form reference is not needed. Therefore you have the CVA Interface so you can use it in any reactive form.

Comment: @Eliseo I tried it and updated the stackblitz but the problem remains. I think I already tried it once but I'm not sure about it.